# Is there a possible race condition in this UPDATE statement?

Tags: sql-server, timestamp, race-condition, rowversion, database-concurrency

I'm writing a synchronizer software which will take all changes in one DB and synchronize them to another DB. To this end I've added in my table `T` two columns:

```
alter table T add LastUpdate rowversion, LastSync binary(8) not null default 0
```

Now I can easily select all rows that have changed since the last synchronization:

```
select * from T where LastUpdate > LastSync
```

However after performing the synchronization I should make the two fields equal. But updating the row also updates the timestamp, so I must do this:

```
update T set LastSync=@@DBTS+1 where ID=@syncedId
```

But I'm wondering - will this always work? What if I read the value of `@@DBTS` and then another user manages to insert/update a row somewhere before my row is committed? Is this risky code? And if yes - how could it be made better?

Comment: By the way what version and edition of SQL Server are you on? Is [Change Data Capture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522489.aspx) an option?

Comment: @Martin Smith - 2008, I think. Not sure what the client has.

Comment: @Martin Smith - I checked out the change data capture, but that would be an overkill. A simple timestamp will suffice. I only need to know which records still need to be sync'ed. I don't need the full history.

Answer (score 4):

Storing "LastSync" in the same table as the real data is maybe not a good idea at all. 
Try storing it in another Table that doesn't have a rowversion. That way you avoid the "updating the row also updates the timestamp"-problem.

Your synchronizer software can then work this way:

- Get the @LastSync value from the additional table
- "Select @ThisSync = max(LastUpdate) from T where LastUpdate > @LastSync"
- "Select * from T where LastUpdate > @LastSync and LastUpdate <= @ThisSync" are your rows for sync
- Store @ThisSync as the new "LastSync" in the additional table.

Entries that are modified while the synchronization is running will have a higher rowversion value than the max() query. They will be synchronized the next time your synchronizer is called.

Comment: That's an idea. I'll keep it in mind, in case nothing better comes up.

Answer (score -1):

If you run this in a `Serializable` transaction then no other reads/writes will be able to affect these tables.

`RepeateableRead` may also do the job...

Comment: Tables - yes. But what about the value of `@@DBTS`? That isn't stored in any table!

Comment: @Vilx If you take an exclusive table lock for the duration of the synchronisation then presumably it doesn't matter if `@@DBTS` gets incremented by an event in another table though.

Comment: @Martin Smith - but @@DBTS is global for the whole DB. Why doesn't it matter? If I get one (older) value for `LastSync` field, and a newer for the `LastUpdate` field, my synchronization will be broken.

Comment: @Vilx Well if you update the table and the value of `@@DBTS` is 10 then another table gets a couple of rows updated making the value of `@@DBTS` equal to 12 and you end up storing 12 in the `LastSync` field why is that a problem? Next time you come to synchronise you are still looking for rows where `LastUpdate > LastSync`.

Comment: @Martin Smith - the problem is that it's the other way round. `LastUpdate` gets the value **after** `LastSync`. Otherwise I wouldn't need that `+1` in the query in the first place.